# How to check build configurations on prebuild event in Xamarin Studio

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross, xamarin-studio

I want to perform some tasks based on my build configuration i.e; **debug or release** mode in one of my iOS Xamarin project.
For this purpose I have written a shell script snippet in an .sh file, below is my snippet,

if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = “Release” ];

then

echo In Release Configuration

else

echo In Development Configuration

fi

and I have done configuration build settings changes accordingly, i.e; given the path for this script file in before build settings, in **custom commands** tab.
My script is getting run before build process as expected but **always my *if condition* inside script is getting failed. It is not able to get the current configuration**.

Can anybody guide me how to get the configuration during or before building the source code in xamarin studio in mac.
Any help is appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using add parameters to Command line after build script f.e. "Script/script.sh 1"

And in script I check $1 if is equal to 1 if yes I was on debug.

Not best solution but solved my problem.

[image]